# Credit Card Validation, I understand it in theory. but coding it is a nightmare for me

Tags: java

I have this assignment due for class. it involved Luans algorithm. if you're not familiar it is the following.

A credit card must have between 13 and 16 digits. It must start with:

• 4 for Visa cards

• 5 for Master cards

• 37 for American Express cards

Almost all credit card numbers are generated following this validity check, commonly know as the Luhn check or the Modulus 10 check, which can be described as follows. For illustration, consider the card number 4388576018402625.

Double every second digit from right to left. If doubling of a digit results in a 2-digit number, add up the two digits to get a single-digit number.
2 x 2 = 4

2 x 2 = 4

4 x 2 = 8

1 x 2 = 2

6 x 2 = 12 (1+2= 3)

5 x 2 = 10 (1+0= 1)

8 x 2 = 16 (1+6= 7)

4 x 2 = 8

Add all the single digit numbers from step 1 4 + 4 +8 + 2 +3 + 1 + 7 + 8 = 37
Add all digits in the odd places from right to left in the card number
5 + 6 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 7 + 8 + 3 = 37

Sum the results from step 2 and step 3 37 + 37 = 74
If the result from step is divisible by 10, the card number is valid; otherwise, it’s invalid.

```
public class NinthProject {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int card;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.print("Enter a credit card number as a long integer:");
    card=in.nextInt();}

    public static boolean isValid(long card){
        boolean valid   = false;
            int sumEven = sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(card);
            int sumOdd  = sumOfOddPlace(card);
            int size    = getSize(card);
            long prefix = getPrefix(card, 1);

        if(prefix == 4 || prefix == 5 || prefix == 6 || prefixMatched(card,37)){
            if(size > 12 && size < 17){
                if((sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(card)  +  sumOfOddPlace(card)) % 10 == 0){
                    valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
        return valid;

}
    public static int sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(long card) {
            int sum = 0;
            int place = 1;
                String stringified = String.valueOf(card);

            for(int i = stringified.length()-1; i > -1; i--) {
                if (place % 2 == 0) {
                    sum += getDigit(Character.getNumericValue(stringified.charAt(i)) * 2);
            }

            place++;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int getDigit(int card){
            String parsed = String.valueOf(card);
            int value;

        if (parsed.length()>1){
            value = Integer.parseInt(parsed.substring(0,1)) + Integer.parseInt(parsed.substring(1,2));
        }
        else {
           value = card;
        }

    return value;
    }

    public static int sumOfOddPlace(long number) {
        int sum = 0;
        int place = 1;
            String stringified = String.valueOf(number);
        for (int i = stringified.length()-1; i > -1; i--) {
            if (place % 2 > 0) {
             sum += Character.getNumericValue(stringified.charAt(i));
        }

        place++;
    }

    return sum;
}

    public static boolean prefixMatched(long number, int d) {
        return String.valueOf(number).startsWith(String.valueOf(d));

}
    public static int getSize(long d) {
        return String.valueOf(d).length();    
    }



    public static long getPrefix(long card, int k) {
        long prefix = card;

    if (card >= Math.pow(10, k)) {
        prefix = Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(card).substring(0, k));
    }

    return prefix;
}
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. It is spitting the following error
(I am terrible at debugging)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "4321098765432109"
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2123)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at ninth.project.NinthProject.main(NinthProject.java:26)
/Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 14 seconds)
```

Comment: try `nextLong()` instead of nextInt

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` gives `2147483647`

Comment: it could help if I setup a System.out.println(card+ " is " + valid);

Comment: Why use a numeric type anyway? Keep it as String.

Comment: some guys down-vote my answer so here is my answer The max value of an int is : 2147483647 and the min is -2147483648

so to solve your problem you have to use Double max = `1.7976931348623157E308` min = `4.9E-324`

Comment: @YCF_L may be because `double` doesn't provide **exact** values?

Comment: I cannot get it to print the card number and if its valid

Comment: Someone already gaves you a good hint: get it as `String` and then parse each char, convert it to corresponding number, etc.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès what did you mean exact value `Double.MAX_VALUE > 4321098765432109L = true` so where is the problem here?

Comment: Suppose a card number starts with 9 and try... `double` doesn't provide exact arithmetic, number are sometimes rounded you know...

Comment: I am currently able to get it to print it that it is invalid, because of the math. I am not understanding where I'm going wrong. I put in a number and I am getting a weird sum and invalid.

Comment: Your problem seems to me more that you are struggling to debug your program than getting a quick fix. If you are not using an IDE and can debug by stepping through your code, I would suggest adding print statements for each value returned by your methods and verifying that each one is working as expected. That should give you an idea of what is going wrong. Also, read the exception an see where your class is mentioned, it will point to the actual problem you are having.